# Syntax higlighters for RPG And CLP that generate HTML and/or RTF?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, ibm-midrange, rpg, control-language

I [found](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/delphi-and-cobol-syntax-highlighters/) that [ToHtml.com](http://tohtml.com/) has a nice bunch of syntax highlightes that generate [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp).

But they don't include [RPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_RPG) or [CLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AS/400_Control_Language).

So: *anyone who knows a syntax highlighter for RPG or/and CLP that generates either HTML or RTF?*

Some more references

- the [custom brushes](http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/09/list-of-brushes-syntaxhighligher/) for [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) does display RPG, but it doesn't generate HTML that you can copy to the clipboard; [SyntaxHighlighterModified](http://syntaxhighlighter.relic19.net/moreinfo.html) does, but it is hard to integrate custom brushes like the RPG one
- [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/), [BlogTrog](http://www.blogtrog.com/), [CodeHtmlEr](http://puzzleware.net/codehtmler/default.aspx) and [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) do not do CLP nor RPG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same need for awhile and finally bit the bullet and created an `RPG mode` for the [Ace Editor](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about).  You can see it [here](https://gist.github.com/aaronbartell/8f711908eec9601ee28e).  I also [modified the Ace "Tomorrow" theme](https://gist.github.com/aaronbartell/dacfc932c6671029235f) to have more RPG features.

I was going to fork/pull the Ace Editor and add this, but they have a more laborious contribution scenario so I haven't taken the time to do that yet.

Been using it for browser-based code documentation.  See below.
[image]

**EDIT:**
Another option is using [VSCode](http://code.visualstudio.com).  They added a feature to the latest version that allows copying the source from VSCode and pasting it into the medium of your choice (presentation, email, etc) fully marked up with syntax coloring.  Couple that with the [VSCode RPG Syntax plugin](https://github.com/NielsLiisberg/RPG-for-VSCode) and you have a winning solution.

Answer (score 1):

We would have to create the highlighters. I haven't looked and any in dept to see how complicated it would would be. Most of them are open-source and would gladly accept the new languages.

Comment: I know, but I don't know enough of the RPG or CLP syntax to be able to contribute to those highlighters. Do you know enough, and have enough time to contribute?

Comment: IBM has the full documentation online. I personally don't have any time for quite a while. Asking on the [RPG-L](http://murl.me/rpgl) mailing list might generate a couple takers.

Comment: The mailing list is a great resource... but you may need to wait a while for any responses.  Your first post is held for moderator approval, and who knows when the moderator will get around to it.  (It's been 5 days for me so far on RPG400-L, 6 days on MIDRANGE-L.)

Comment: @John, I'm the moderator of both RPG400-L & MIDRANGE-L.  Please contact me at support@midrange.com about the turnaround time on your posts.

Comment: @david (and any readers considering subscribing to the midrange lists):  The delay issue appears resolved, and I encourage anyone with relevant questions to try asking on those lists.